# Xrandr doesn't find HDMI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia

I am unable to connect to an external monitor via HDMI. The HDMI port works fine with Windows 10 but not Ubuntu 16.04.

System specs:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Kernel: 4.4.0-96-generic

GPU: Nvidia Quadro M2000M

Nvidia driver: 384.111

The driver and GPU are compatable according to: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/128737/en-us

Output of Xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output of sudo lshw -C video:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3000000-d3ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:d4000000-d407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure this out by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with my RTX 2060. I had already installed the latest Nvidia driver (nvidia-520), but it looks like the latest versions of Nvidia drivers are causing several issues. I could solve this by downgrading the driver;

First, uninstall all Nvidia drivers on your computer:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

After that, you should install **nvidia-driver-460-server**. It seems to be the best one until now.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460-server
```

Now you should reboot, connect your monitor and it should work.
If not, try to disable the secure boot on your computer.

Best of luck!